# Laravel whereIn() acting like orWhereIn()

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

There are 3 tables:

1. meals
2. tags
3. meal_tag

I want to get all meals that have all of the tags from an url query.

For example: `.../api/query?tags=1,2,3`

In this example I want to fetch all meals that have

> tag1 **AND** tag2 **AND** tag3

,but my query returns meals that have

> tag1 **OR** tag2 **OR** tag3

Here is my query:

```
   $query = Meal::query();  
   ...

   if ($request->has('tags')) {

        $inputTags = $request->query('tags');

        $tags = explode(',', $inputTags);


        $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tags) {
            $q->whereIn('tags.id', $tags);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN()` checks whether a value is within a set of values, for any value matched then return true, It doesn't verify for all values to be present,

To achieve for what you are trying you need to check each tag id individually using `whereHas` to make sure all of these are present

```
if ($request->has('tags')) {
    $inputTags = $request->query('tags');
    $tags = explode(',', $inputTags);
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $query = $query->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($tag) {
            $q->where('id','=', $tag);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you for a quick answer,I'll accept in 5 minutes, stack overflow is not allowing it yet